# What is the English equivalent of gatasan?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, nouns

It literally means *to milk*. It also means a dairy cow.
It could be both a noun or verb.

> *v.* To use someone for the money he/she can give you.
>
> *n.* Someone (a girlfriend, husband) that you milk for money.

Comment: There is the term *cash cow* but which is usually applied to a business or investment that provides a steady income or profit. (Oxford Online)

Comment: Can you write an example sentence where the word would be used as a noun and a verb? What does your native language to English dictionary say?

Comment: As you describe, I don't think there'll be a single word (*to milk* / *something that is milked*). You'd be looking at words like *freeload/er*, *to sponge*, *parasite*, *leech* and many others depending on precise context/intent.

Answer (score 1):

As a verb meaning to use someone for their money:

- *Gold digging* - this is more seen in noun form as *gold digger*, a person engaging in such activities as the receiver.

As a noun for a person being used in such fashion:

- *Sugar daddy*, and the feminine *sugar mommy* (a lot rarer). This generally implies the person is willing to give away money as "payment" for attention, sex, or similar things.

Both of these are about a specific kind of relationship, where money is given for fulfilling expectations normally seen in a romantic relationship. Essentially, this describes couples where one of the parties is rich, and the other party is after the money.

For other uses, there are options already mentioned in the comments:

- *freeloading*, *mooching*, *leeching* - these all carry negative connotations
- I cannot come up with a single word for a person who allows freeloading, mooching, leeching etc, but one can say they are *enabling* the behaviour by giving away wealth in this manner.